# Can't call a class inside of my activity

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments, android-activity

I have this class:

```
public class SayingsHolder extends Application{

    ArrayList<String> SayingsList = new ArrayList<String>(){{
        SayingsList.add("1");
        SayingsList.add("2");

    }};

    public ArrayList<String> getSayingsList() {
        return SayingsList;
    }


}
```

Now I'm trying to call it in my activity's `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` by:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    String[] displayText;

    final SayingsHolder holder = (SayingsHolder).getApplication();

    String names[] = {"1","2","3"};
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,String[] displayText) {
        super(fm);
        this.displayText=displayText;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        System.out.println(position);
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment(); 
        fragment.setText(names[position]);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }    
}
```

But it gives me this error:

`SayingsHolder cannot be resolved to a variable`

What am I missing here? I know that I'm referring wrong to the class, but I can't find a way to fix it. Can someone give me a small clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
final SayingsHolder holder = (SayingsHolder).getApplication();
```

to

```
final SayingsHolder holder = (SayingsHolder)getApplication();
```

Comment: Yes, seems to be working, even if I can't reffer to the get method. Anyways. Thanks for teh help! :)